# Input and output shape to GRU layer in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, gated-recurrent-unit

I am getting confused about the input shape to GRU layer.
I have a batch of 128 images and I extracted 9 features from each images.
So now my shape is `(1,128,9)`.

This is the GRU layer

```
gru=torch.nn.GRU(input_size=128,hidden_size=8,batch_first=True)
```

**Question 1: Is the `input_size=128` correctly defined**?
Here is the code of forward function

```
def forward(features):
    features=features.permute(0,2,1)#[1, 9, 128]
    x2,_=self.gru(features)
```

**Question 2: Is the `code in forward function is correctly defined**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, `input_size` is not correctly defined. Here, `input_size` means the number of features in a single input vector of the sequence. The input to the GRU is a sequence of vectors, each input being a 1-D tensor of length `input_size`. In case of batched input, the input to GRU is a batch of sequence of vectors, so the shape should be `(batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)` when `batch_first=True` otherwise the expected shape is `(sequence_length, batch_size, input_size)` when `batch_first=False`

```
import torch

batch_size = 128 
input_size = 9  # features in the input
seq_len = 5 # seqence length - how many input vectors in one sequence

hidden_size = 20 # the no of fetures in the output of GRU

gru=torch.nn.GRU(input_size=input_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,batch_first=True)

X = torch.rand( (batch_size, seq_len, input_size), dtype = torch.float32 )
print(f'{X.shape=}')

Y,_ = gru(X)
print(f'{Y.shape=}')
```

output

```
"""
X.shape=torch.Size([128, 5, 9])
Y.shape=torch.Size([128, 5, 20])
"""
```

Using `batch_first=False`

```
gru=torch.nn.GRU(input_size=input_size,hidden_size=hidden_size,batch_first=False)

X = torch.rand( (seq_len, batch_size, input_size), dtype = torch.float32 )
print(f'{X.shape=}')

Y,_ = gru(X)
print(f'{Y.shape=}')
```

output

```
"""
X.shape=torch.Size([5, 128, 9])
Y.shape=torch.Size([5, 128, 20])
"""
```